# What is the Guru-parampara of Sri Ramakrishna's Vedanta-sadhana?

Tags: ramakrishna

Can someone provide the Guru-parampara of Bhagavan Sri Ramakrishna's Vedanta Sadhana? He was a disciple of Sri Totapuri as an Advaintin Monk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According Swami Alokananda,Totapuri was a dasanami monk of the naga sect.His Marhi started with Bhagavan Puri. Siddha Baba Rajpuri built an ashram at Baba Ladana near Kaithal where from Totapuri went out for parivrajana and came to Dakshineswar wandering at various places.The lineage is

> Bhagavan Puri >Jagmohan Puri > Janged Puri > Haridwar Puri > Manasa Puri > Saraswati Puri > Raj Puri > Siddha Puri > Bhandar Puri > Dalel Puri > Jnan Puri > Tota Puri > Sri Ramakrishna Paramahansa

Reference : http://www.rkmdelhi.org/articles/srimat-totapuris-origins-in-ladana-haryana/[image]

Comment: What is the Guru Parampara of Bhagavan Puri?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan  Bhagavan Puri was a dasnami naga sect of Puti lineage and belonged to the Mahanirvani Akhada.The details of Puri sect I have given in answer of a different question already. It stars from Adi Shankaracharya of course, whose Adi Guru was Sriman Narayana

Comment: But do we know who Bhagavan Puri’s direct Guru was?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan no that information is not available

Comment: @user17294- it is incorrect to connect Adi Shankara with Bhagavan Puri or his parampara...Adi Shankara only has the four Amnaya Peethas established in four parts of India which are having an unbroken chain of Jagadgurus. Ramakrishna Paramhamsa does not come from that order..in fact he was a householder poojari...